# Is the global name 'a' in the same namespace as the module?

Tags: python, module, namespaces, global

```
import math

a = 1

def my_func():
    print('don\'t downvote')

my_func()
```

I believe that the function invocation *my_func( )* lies in the local namespace created for the function *my_func( )* - ready for correction. Is the name **a** contained in the same global namespace created for the **math** module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Let's say your file is called `foo.py`. When your module is imported, a new global namespace is created for `foo`, and it contains (among other things) three names:

1. `math`, which refers to the `math` module`
2. `my_func`, which refers to your function
3. `a`, which refers to 1

Where your function is called doesn't really matter. If `my_func` contained any free variables, they would *always* refer to `foo`'s global namespace, not the namespace where it is called.

The `math` module has its own global namespace. ("Global" really isn't a good term; each module has its own module-level namespace.)

The only "global" namespace in Python is the built-in namespace, which is accessible from all modules.

Comment: *"If my_func contained any free variables, they would always refer to foo's global namespace, not the namespace where it is called."* - By this, are you implying that if ```my_func``` contains the statement ```b = 1```, then ```b```will be present in the global namespace of ```foo```? I believe that every function has it's own namespace. I think that I got your statement wrong.

Comment: Not quite. With `b = 1`, `b` would be *defined* as a local variable. But if you had `print(b)` with no other definition of `b` inside the function, `b` would be a free variable, and would resolve to the first definition of `b` found in an enclosing scope. Here, the only enclosing scope is the global scope, but additional non-local scopes could be present if, for example, `my_func` were defined inside another function definition.

Comment: Hey, last question. Suppose ```my_func()``` contains two statements: ```print(x); print(dir())``` - Here ```x``` is a free variable. The output by the statement ```print(dir())``` is an empty list ```[]```. Was the local namespace created but didn't contain any name or it wasn't created at all?

Comment: That's something of a "what is the sound of one hand clapping?" question :) I suspect for ease of implementation, though, a local namespace is always created, even if it doesn't actually contain anything.